# Centering the nested divs and table header design

Tags: css

I am a newbie when it comes to CSS, can anyone help me with centering a 3-level divs? The thing is the width is unknown since I am using %. I've already tried `margin: auto;` but didn't work.

And am also facing another problem with table headers and footers. I've tried putting up
a horizontal line with `<hr>` code in the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` but they didn't appear the wait I want them to be. I am already lost, please help me.

[Click here to view my current code on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebozar/1)

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 100%;padding:1% 0% 0% 0.5%;margin:0 auto;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px;background: #E0E0E0 !important;border: 1px solid #808080;">
<div style="width:45%;margin: 0 1.5%;float:left;">
    <div style="width: 100%;text-align: right !important;white-space: nowrap;">
        <b>Select</b> &nbsp;
        <select name="department" id="department" class="required" style="margin-top:0.4%; margin-right: -4px; width: 70%;">
            <option class="options" value="">Please select</option>
                <option class="options" value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option class="options" value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option class="options" value="3">Option 3</option>
                <option class="options" value="4">Option 4</option>
                <option class="options" value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px !important;margin-bottom: -100px !important;height: 220px;width: 100%;background: #BFBABA !important;border-radius: 5px;border: 4px solid #BFBABA" >
        <div class="taskhead" style="margin-bottom: -90px !important;padding: 5px;background-color: #ccffff;height: 200px;margin: auto;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid #808080;">
            <div style="margin: 0px auto!important;padding: 5px;height: 180px; background: #ffffff !important;border: 1px solid #808080;border-radius: 5px;">
                <b>Name:</b>
                <div id="er_users" style="width: 100%;overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 160px; background: #ffffff !important;">
                    <table id="uid" style="width: 100%;margin-left: 5px; float: right;">
                        <thead style="background-color: #e0e0e0"><hr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td>Name 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td>Name 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td>Name 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td>Name 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot style="background-color: #e0e0e0"><hr></tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin: 0 1.5%; background-color: #D6D2D2 !important;width:0.2%;height: 265px !important;float:left;">&nbsp;<br/></div>
<div style="width:45%;margin: 0 1%;float:left;">
    <div style="margin-top: 1%"></div>
    <b>User</b>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px !important;margin-bottom: -100px !important;height: 220px;width: 100%;background: #BFBABA !important;border-radius: 5px;border: 4px solid #BFBABA;" >
        <div style="margin-bottom: -100px !important;padding: 5px;background-color: #e6f0a3;height: 200px;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid #808080;">
            <div style="margin: 0px auto!important;padding: 5px;height: 180px; background: #ffffff !important;border: 1px solid #808080;border-radius: 5px;">
                <b>Name:</b>
                <div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 160px; background: #ffffff !important;">
                    <table id="uid" style="width: 100%;margin-left: 5px; float: right;">
                        <thead style="background-color: #e0e0e0"><hr></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td>Name 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td>Name 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td>Name 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td>Name 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot style="background-color: #e0e0e0"><hr></tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the way my table should look like

[Click here to view the image](http://oi50.tinypic.com/k9as6s.jpg)

Comment: [I have found this blog talking about centering the unknown size but even this didn't do the trick.](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: [This is the closest thing I've done to mimic the desired output. As you can see, the padding on top is bigger than the padding on the bottom, I don't why though I've set `padding` to one size](http://jsbin.com/ulerus/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you increase `margin-top` below **User** to `15px` the tables align vertically.

For the horizontal rules, move `tfoot` up before `tbody`, and wrap `hr` with `tr td`

```
<thead><tr><td><hr/></td></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr><td><hr/></td></tr></tfoot>
```

To extend the `table` to the enclosing `div`, add

```
height: 100%;
```

to the `table`.

Modified [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ebozar/10)

Comment: thanks for taking your time to answer my question @Olaf Dietsche but sadly your proposed solution is not the one I am seeking.

Comment: @Darth Then you should clarify, what exactly doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @Darth You can do that, but then it doesn't look like your image. Please see updated answer.

Comment: my bad. As you've mentioned, I've placed `border-top: 3px solid #e0e0e0;` `border-bottom: 3px solid #e0e0e0` on the enclosing `div` but the horizontal rules should be inside and part of the `<table>`. I've tried putting it there but there was no horizontal rule displayed.

Comment: thanks again @Olaf Dietsche but how about fixing horizontal rule at the bottom aligned with the scrollbars just like the one on the top?

Comment: @Darth I finally found out what was wrong with `thead` and `tfoot`, please see updated answer and JSBin.

Comment: @Darth The scrollbar is from the enclosing `div` not the `table`, that's why I attached the horizontal rules to the div in the first try.

Comment: @Darth Finally, this should work as you expect. See updated answer and JSBin.

Comment: thanks for your extensive support but still the `<tfoot>` wasn't placed in parallel with the scrollbars.

Comment: @Darth A final note, you should extract the inline styles to a separate css file, since this is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: It did, but how can I set the height of `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`? Say I want it 3px? Putting up _height_ on the style doesn't change it.

Comment: @Darth I tried too, but I can't see how this could be done. It seems, all rows, including head and foot, must be the same height.

Comment: that's fine. Thanks for taking your time helping me.